# Does App Engine automatically load balance if we configure it to auto-scale?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, autoscaling

Does App Engine automatically load balance if we configure the App Engine to auto-scale? Or do we manually need to add a load balancer for an app hosted on App Engine?

I just started learning GCP this week and I have been given an assignment by my trainer to deploy an application on App Engine and to connect it to a load balancer and a CDN. I have understood how to use load balancers with Compute Engine. But since App Engine takes care of auto-scaling without us having to configure anything, does it also take care of load-balancing automatically? Or do we have to manually setup a load balancer? I tried to search a lot about load balancers with App Engine but the only thing I could find was some "Network Endpoint Groups(NEG)". I couldn't understand any of NEG articles because I am not familiar with containers and Kubernetes. Can someone please explain load balancing for App Engine and how to do it?

Comment: App Engine auto scales, if configured correctly. The purpose of deploying a Google Load Balancer is to add App Engine as a backend. This could be for URL Maps, failover, etc. App Engine has a load balancer called the GFE (Google Front End). That does not negate the benefits of another load balancer that distributes traffic to different services based upon request URLs. Some requests might go to Cloud Storage (CSS, JS, images), some requests go to your App Engine service, some requests go to Cloud Run or Cloud Functions or even an on-premises server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GAE includes a load balancer.  As soon as you scale to 2 instances, this is necessary and GAE takes care of it for you.  GAE does an amazing job of taking care of this for you (much better than AWS Elastic Beanstalk for example).

For more complicated situations (e.g., Kubernetes), you can manually create and configure a load balancer. I don't think you would ever you use a custom load balancer with GAE.